# Cannot GET /api/forge/oauth/callback

Tags: autodesk-forge

Im trying to test out this demo on my own windows machine: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashissue

Ive successfully started had the template running with these commands.

```
npm install
set FORGE_CLIENT_ID=<<YOUR CLIENT ID FROM DEVELOPER PORTAL>>
set FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=<<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>>
set FORGE_CALLBACK_URL=<<YOUR CALLBACK URL>>
npm run nodemon
```

Ive added a new app within the Forge My Apps interface.
Ive added the provisions for the the BIM 360 Account interface.

I can connect to my localhost, and when i press ALLOW to try to authenticate and login to the autodesk account, i get redirected to the following website with the following error:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oauth/callback?code=TOAq...

Cannot GET /api/forge/oauth/callback
```

How can i get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a configuration mismatch. You have configured the callback to be `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oauth/callback` but according to https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashissue/blob/master/server/endpoints/oauth.endpoints.js#L72 your server actually expects the callback on a different URL: `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth`.